# работа с api google translate c#

Tags: c#, google-translate

Нужно реализовать консольную програму запроса к гугл переводчику на c#.
Уперся в то что api GoogleTranslate вроде как платные. Есть ли способ получать url с сайта и смотреть там перевод в поле check_box

Comment: Есть ли получать url с сайта - то перевода там не увидите. Самый правильный вариант использовать [Google Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/)

Answer (score -1):

Можно попробовать с небольшими текстами генерить следующий адрес страницы используя плюсы вместо побелов:

```
 https://translate.google.com/#ЯзыкСКоторогоПереводить/НаКоторый/Hello+Word
```

и получится

```
 https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/Hello+Word
```

и покажет тебе страницу, которая переводит тебе текст.
Можешь делать запрос на даный адрес, получать ответ от сервера и потом парсить хтмл через htmlAgilityPack

Таким макаром получишь результат, даже, независимо от того что Google Translate API платный, как ты говоришь.